# Shadow PC client unable to connect to Shadow PC on Ubuntu. Error code R-0x7F

Tags: shadow

I cannot start my shadow pc.  It starts up and acts like it will connect but then fails at the last moment with Error code: R-0x7F.

Attempts to fix the issue on my part:

1. Tried on android and ubuntu.  Both the same issue.
2. Using the troubleshooting, tried shutting down the shadowpc and attempting to access again.
3. Using the troubleshooting, tried shutting down the shadowpc.  Then attempted to start in safe mode using the safe mode option in troublshooting
4. I reset the shadowpc from my account web page.
5. Attempted steps recommended by Bot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honsiedog from Shadow Support shared these libs for me to install, after install, works great!

`sudo apt install gconf2 libgles2-mesa libubsan0 libuv1 libva-glx2`

Comment: This is the way

Comment: This did not help on Ubuntu 20.10

Comment: Oh darn, if you find a solution, go ahead and post an answer below, I'll upvote it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a snippet to explain how install and fix it: https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2189195

Download the libraries: [shadow.asarLibs.zip](https://gitlab.com/uploads/-/system/personal_snippet/2189195/c0b55d86a01266c2dfe49b7b325fabe5/shadow.asarLibs.zip)

```bsh
wget https://gitlab.com/uploads/-/system/personal_snippet/2189195/c0b55d86a01266c2dfe49b7b325fabe5/shadow.asarLibs.zip &&
md5sum shadow.asarLibs.zip &&
sha256sum shadow.asarLibs.zip
```

```
md5: d88c887caf48cb312578f1dd3ae0908a  shadow.asarLibs.zip
sha256: 5dea80353a70b7eed8a24375460562900b7598207354b261628a6c17a56a63a3 shadow.asarLibs.zip
```

Extract the zip file:

```bsh
unzip shadow.asarLibs.zip
```

```
Archive:  shadow.asarLibs.zip
   creating: asarLibs/
  inflating: asarLibs/libasn1.so.8   
  inflating: asarLibs/libheimbase.so.1  
  inflating: asarLibs/libheimntlm.so.0  
  inflating: asarLibs/libroken.so.18  
  inflating: asarLibs/libldap_r-2.4.so.2  
  inflating: asarLibs/libhcrypto.so.4  
  inflating: asarLibs/libgssapi.so.3  
  inflating: asarLibs/libkrb5.so.26  
  inflating: asarLibs/liblber-2.4.so.2  
  inflating: asarLibs/libhx509.so.5  
  inflating: asarLibs/libwind.so.0
```

Create a new file `ShadowFix.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
current="`dirname "$0"`"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$current/asarLibs:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
$current/Shadow.AppImage
```

Allow the program to run and start it:

```bsh
chmod +x ./ShadowFix.sh &&
./ShadowFix.sh
```